# Need some help writing to a csv file

Tags: perl, csv

I am new to perl I need some help to write my output to the last column of the csv file after some operations on a single row. I am using Text::CSV_XS module in perl. I know the statement to write to a csv file is print FH "sitepoint, 2, 7\n" ; But how to write to a specific column like 5th column ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`Text::CSV` docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CSV/):

> When writing CSV files with `always_quote` set, the unquoted empty field is the result of an undefined value.

Thus, if you do something like:

```
my @arr = ( undef, undef, undef, undef, "5th column" );
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { always_quote => 1 } );
open my $fh, '>', 'outfile.csv' or die $!;
$csv->print( $fh, \@arr );
```

...you should get an output file of the form

```
,,,,5th column
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ",,,,5th column\n";
```

That will write to the 5th column. Each `,` shifts to the next column. Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444096/how-do-i-create-a-csv-file-using-perl).

Comment: your solution is not working for me. Nothing is being written. I think the problem is with the opening the file itself. Is this correct?

Comment: @mousey Have you included the file handle? The above was only demonstrating what to print.

Comment: I included an +>>. its still not working. Now I am unable to read too. What might be the problem