# Write command output to a csv file in perl

Tags: shell, perl

I am trying to write a command output to a csv file .Below is the command i want to use to write the data into a csv file

```
ps -eo pid,comm,pmem,vsz | grep process  | awk '{print $1",",$2",",$3",",$4}'
```

How we can do this in Perl . Header of the csv file should have and then corresponding values for this :

```
pid,comm,pmem,vsz
```

I was trying to do something like this but it is not working for me :

```
echo "execution started.."

pid,comm,pmem,vsz >> out.txt

while [ true ]; do
    echo "running.."
    sleep 2
    ps -eo pid,comm,pmem,vsz | grep process  | awk '{print $1",",$2",",$3",",$4}' >> out.txt
done
```

Comment: Remember that the CSV format requires escaping any quotes that might appear in your data.

Comment: For Perl solutions see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444096/how-do-i-create-a-csv-file-using-perl).

Comment: Which part of this are you having trouble with? The `ps` part, the `grep` part, or the `awk` part? Are you trying to do all of this in Perl without calling `ps`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "is not working"? Please provide a [mcve]. Also, none of your code uses Perl, so how is this related to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444096/how-do-i-create-a-csv-file-using-perl) in the comment by [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) has a lot of information, but you can also do

```
ps -eo pid,comm,pmem,vsz | grep process_name | 
    perl -nE '
        BEGIN { say "pid,comm,pmem,vsz" }; 
        say join ",", split
    ' > ps_process.out
```

(broken into multiple lines for readability)

The `BEGIN` block is executed only in the compilation phase so it's not repeated in iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward way, using the `-a` switch to implicity create `@F` for each line piped in (it's a shortcut for saying `@F = split /\s+\, $_`)

```
echo pid,comm,pmem,vsz > out.csv
ps -eo pid,comm,pmem,vsz | perl -lnaE 'say join ",", @F' >> out.csv
```